# Vim: How to refresh the page to get rid of the double lines?

Tags: vim

[image]

Sometimes when I save a file I see double lines appearing at the bottom of my screen.

I mapped my Ctrl-L to something else so these method are **not able** to refresh my screen to get rid of these double lines:

- `:noh`
- `:redraw`

Any recommendations?

Comment: Have you tried `:redrawstatus` or `:redrawstatus!`?

Answer (score 0):

In Insert mode, you can use `<C-V>` before a key to avoid mappings defined for that key, but I cannot find anything similar for Normal mode.

One work-around is to use the `:normal` command with the `!` modifier.  Depending on whether you want to avoid typing raw characters on the command line, try

```
:normal!CTRL-L
```

(where `CTRL-L` means a single character) or

```
:execute "normal!\<C-L>"
```

(type it as you see it).  See `:help :normal` for details (including how to use it with `:execute`).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd try to find out what's causing these double messages; perhaps you can avoid those.

Your screenshot looks suspicious; what's that `:w` after the first `"models.py" written` message; did you type that?! And what's that grey block after that message? These may be indications that your terminal isn't set up properly.

---

To clear any unwanted lingering messages, it's usually sufficient to enter and leave the command-line, e.g. with `:<CR>`. As the command-line occupies the same space as the messages, this effectively clears it.